# Two rocker switches stopped working after replacement

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I replaced 20-30 switches in the house today, and all but two (which coincidentally share the same double gang box) work. I've tried re-terminating the wires, swapping wires, and trying a different switch, but they no longer turn on.

I checked all of the gfci outlets in the house to make sure that wasn't causing an issue. Unfortunately, I don't have a voltage tester so I'm hoping that including these pics may lead to the issue for someone more experienced.

I'm happy to bring in an electrician if I have to, but I wanted to check here first.

Thanks in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGKzT.jpg

Comment: *I don't have a voltage tester* What do you have? I never even use my voltage tester for tracing house wiring. I use a 25W desk lamp with insulated probes instead of a plug.

Comment: You replaced 20 switches and don't have a voltage tester? That's crazy! Get yourself a multimeter and a non-contact tester. I've got a [set like this Klein](https://amzn.to/3bcxKWp) but there are plenty of others. And post pictures showing the wiring of the problem switches.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri A non-contact tester is cheap insurance to make sure things are dead when they should be (to work on them) and live when they should be. A multimeter can help you quickly track down hot/neutral swaps, shorts, etc. They are basic tools for the job.

Comment: Yeah, I have all that stuff, and I use it when appropriate. But when tracing house wiring, my non-contact tester and multimeter tend to react to nearby wires, phantom voltages, and other things that are not there. I just don't believe a wire is hot until I power a load from it.

Comment: Don't guess/experiment. There are many combinations which will work (you'll stop at that point) *but will kill you*.

Comment: The general rule is that you can use NCVTs for preliminary investigation and a safety check before handling a circuit you believe to be dead.  If you need to know for sure you use a multimeter.  OP you need to provide a picture of the box in question with all wires visible.   And buy or borrow the multimeter and volt ticker of course.  They're not expensive.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I wish you'd quit saying "it will kill you". While we all need to have respect for electricity, the percentage of people who are actually electrocuted (killed) vs. those who just got a shock is incredibly small.  I've gotten quite a few nasty shocks.  One time I was replacing outlets in my son's old house with tamper resistant ones for his kids rooms....I had the power off (I thought) for all 4 outlets, but the last one was on a different circuit. I got bit, but survived! And am hear to tell you about it.

Comment: Thanks all - here is a link with the pictures:  https://imgur.com/a/gj9qINF

Comment: No!  Bad OP!  You can hit the edit button at the bottom of your question to add required information.  If you put it in the comments people have to click a link and the information will also eventually disappear.

Comment: Take a look at this diagram. It's not your set of boxes, but this is what I mean when I say every wire must be visible. We have to be able to see how the wires are grouped into conduits or cables so we can tell you what to open up or meter to figure out the correct connection. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cMlx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cMlx.png)

Comment: @KH -- that's the same link they posted in their Q originally, and yes, it includes pictures looking into the back of the box

Comment: Try to draw wiring diagram and may be you find the problem. Your pics is not enough informative.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Hmm hadn't noticed the extra pics, although they're not adequately clear they're close.  Do we consider external links to imgur permanent?  I'm pretty sure it should still be inline with the picture tool.  Looks like 3 cables but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Just to update - there were additional wires in a nearby outlet I replaced that were somehow associated with these switches. Although the outlet worked, it wasn’t until I reterminated those extra wires into the new outlet that the switches started working again.